# Tor Vidalia Browser Problem

Tags: browser, tor, vidalia

So Vidalia is up and running fine but the browser has not installed properly, like it has before. Before I just clicked on the onion icon, it would say

**Launching Tor... You are now connected**

The browser would start up and inform me I am connected to network with the browser page.

Now, when I click Vidalia in the menu the onion icon appears at the top of my screen, which informs me I'm connected to the network. I can view a dropdown menu telling me about the network map and control panel but no browser to surf the tor network with. Is it because it's a new version and using firefox normally is basically the same thing, because everything is now going through the tor network that way? Probably I need to alter something or download the Browser separately?
Thanks

Comment: Where did you download the bundle? Or have you integrated Vidalia manually?

Comment: The Ubuntu software centre, downloaded it from there. But the browser does not download with it, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you need to download the web browser which isn’t in the Ubuntu Software Center. This answered my question:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```